# Time and Work : Alternating Workers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, word-problem

**Two taps $A$ and $B$ can fill a tank in $20$ minutes and $30$ minutes respectively. An outlet pipe $C$ can empty the full tank in $15$ minutes. $A$,$B$ and $C$ are opened alternatively each for $1$ minute. How long will the tank take to be filled $?$**

Below is my approach :-

For 1$^{st}$ set of $3$ minutes ; net work done by the opening of two inlet taps and one outlet tap = $\frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{30} - \frac{1}{15} = \frac{1}{60}$

For the $59$ sets of 3 minutes ; work done = $\frac{59}{60}$ $\Rightarrow$ Total time till now = $59\times3=177$ minutes

Work left = $\frac{1}{60}$

Now after $177$ minutes, again tap $A$ will be opened and as we can see that tap $A$ can do $\frac{1}{20}$ units of work in $1$ minute and the units of work left is pretty much smaller quantity i.e. $\frac{1}{60}$ units, then the whole tank will be filled under a minute only by the tap $A$ which means the answer to this problem should lie between $177$ and $178$ minutes but to my bad luck the correct answer has been given as $167$ minutes. Can someone please explain me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What you've done is correct.  I would say it takes $177.3333...$  minutes.  It must be a typo in the answer sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thought that instead of being full at the end of the minute C discharges, which would give $180$ minutes, you should look at shorter times when the tank gets full is a good one but you didn't push it far enough.  After some number $n$ of $3$ minute intervals the tank is $\frac n{60}$ full.  In the next $2$ minutes the $A$ tap fills $\frac 1{20}$ and then $B$ fills $\frac 1{30}$.  We want the tank full at this moment.  We have
$$\frac n{60}+\frac 1{20}+\frac 1{30}=1\\
\frac{n+5}{60}=1\\
n=55$$
The three minute intervals take $3 \cdot 55=165$ minutes, then there are the two minutes for the $A$ and $B$ taps making $167$ in total.

Comment: I am sorry..i did not get you clearly..i mean...till the 177 minutes..tank would still be 1/60 empty...so i just need to turn on the tap A this time and it will fill it,right? why do we need both the taps to open? I understand what you are doing there...you are trying to fill the tank as soon as the B completes the work so that C tap does not come into picture.

Comment: But at $165$ minutes the tank is $\frac {55}{60}$ full.  Then in the next minute $A$ supplies $\frac 3{60}$ and the minute after that $B$ supplies $\frac 2{60}$ so the tank is full at $167$.  Then $C$ comes along and empties $\frac 4{60}$ but we are full well before $177$.  In fact, the tank overflows at $169.5$ and we get in a cycle.  $C$ takes out $\frac 4{60}$, $A$ puts back $\frac 3{60}, B$ puts in $\frac 1{60}$ in $\frac 12$ minute, filling the tank, and the last $30$ seconds of $B$'s turn the tank is overflowing.  We then start with $C$ again.

Comment: Ohhhh..OK....i got it...so tank will be first filled at 167 minutes and then this cycle will continue on...filling==>overflowing==>and C emptying out...but 1st time it will be filled at 167 minutes... understood..thanks!